# ng-repeat, $index and offset problems?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<ul class="stream-informer-short-list">
  <li class="stream-informer-short-list-item" ng-repeat="streamer in streamerItems">
     <a href="stream.html"><img src="{{streamer.imageUrl}}"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How i can use $index for offset first X items?
{{streamer.imageUrl[$index+4}} - work uncorrectly.
Or i must write filter for this action?

Comment: Do you want to offset items in streamerItems or in imageUrl?

Comment: I want offset in streamerItems

Comment: Then shouldn't that be `streamer[$index+4].imageUrl`? Not sure if that will work properly, it will try to create 4 elements where index is larger than the list. Filter does seem like the right approach.

Comment: No, sorry, but its no working. GET error. I mean, i must use offset filter.

Comment: make a copy of `streamerItems` and remove first 4 items in array? Would help to explain how you plan to use the other items later , or if at all

Comment: I need separate streamerItems. Fisrt 4 have one logic, all other another logic.

Comment: still doesn't explain why you couldn't copy the array and remove 4 from copy

Answer (score 1):

ng-switch can be used with $index to allow ng-repeat items to have different HTML:

```
<ul class="stream-informer-short-list">
  <li class="stream-informer-short-list-item" ng-repeat="streamer in streamerItems">
     <span ng-switch on="$index <= 4">
       <a ng-switch-when="true" href="stream.html">
          <img src="{{streamer.imageUrl[$index+4]}}"></a>
       <a ng-switch-default href="stream.html">
          <img src="{{streamer.imageUrl[$index]}}"></a>
     </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Intresting Technique. Big Thanx.